# How do I comment disable all Cron using Ansible

Tags: ansible, cron, updates, disable

Below are my cron entries.

```
$ crontab -l
#Cron to auto restart app1
#Ansible: test
#*/15 * * * * ansible-playbook  /web/playbooks/automation/va_action.yml


#Cron to auto restart app7

#Ansible: test
*/15 * * * * ansible-playbook  /web/playbooks/automation7/va_action.yml | tee -a /web/playbooks/automation7/cron.out


#Cron to restart Apache services on automation server

#Ansible: test
0 2 * * * /web/apps/prod/apache/http-automation/bin/apachectl -k start
```

Below is how I list all enabled Cron

```
crontab -l | grep -v '#' | tr -d '\n'
```

Output:

```
*/15 * * * * ansible-playbook  /web/playbooks/automation7/va_action.yml | tee -a /web/playbooks/automation7/cron.out
0 2 * * * /web/apps/prod/apache/http-automation/bin/apachectl -k start
```

And here is how i list all `#Ansible:` values for cron

```
crontab -l | awk '/^$/ { next ; } /^#/ { text=$2 ; } /^[^#]/ { print text; }'

test
test
```

Here is my Ansible code where I need help.

```
cat handlecron.yml
- name: "cron"
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:

    - raw: "crontab -l | grep -v '#' | tr -d '\n'"
      ignore_errors: true
      register: cronentry

    - cron:
        name: "test"
        job: "{{ item }}"
        state: present
        disabled: True
      with_items:
        - "{{ cronentry.stdout_lines }}"
```

I have given `#Ansible: test` same for all the Cron entries.

I am not sure if I will have to give this as unique entry for the logic to work.

Upon running the automation commented entries for loop `cronentry.stdout_lines` appears under each `#Ansible: test`. This is not what I desire but the desired Cron entries should look like below:

```
$ crontab -l
#Cron to auto restart app1
#Ansible: test
#*/15 * * * * ansible-playbook  /web/playbooks/automation/va_action.yml


#Cron to auto restart app7

#Ansible: test
#*/15 * * * * ansible-playbook  /web/playbooks/automation7/va_action.yml | tee -a /web/playbooks/automation7/cron.out


#Cron to restart apache services on automation server

#Ansible: test
#0 2 * * * /web/apps/prod/apache/http-automation/bin/apachectl -k start
```

Can you please suggest the logic to use here?

Comment: Names have to be unique

Answer (score 0):

Cron jobs can be found in a file under `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/$USERNAME`, which is not intended to be edited directly, but they can be read from there.
`man crontab`

> DESCRIPTION
> crontab is the program used to install, deinstall or list the tables used to drive the cron(8) daemon in Vixie Cron.  Each user can have their own
> crontab, and though these are files in /var/spool/cron/crontabs, they are not intended to be edited directly.

First grep uncommented lines `grep -v "^#" /var/spool/cron/crontabs/$USERNAME`

```yaml
*/15 * * * * ansible-playbook  /web/playbooks/automation7/va_action.yml | tee -a /web/playbooks/automation7/cron.out



0 2 * * * /web/apps/prod/apache/http-automation/bin/apachectl -k start
```

Then grep them without spaces or lines `grep -v "^#" /var/spool/cron/crontabs/$USERNAME | grep -v "^[[:space:]]*$"`

```yaml
*/15 * * * * ansible-playbook  /web/playbooks/automation7/va_action.yml | tee -a /web/playbooks/automation7/cron.out
0 2 * * * /web/apps/prod/apache/http-automation/bin/apachectl -k start
```

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    cron_user: root
  tasks:
  - name: Get enabled cron jobs
    shell: grep -v "^#" /var/spool/cron/crontabs/{{ cron_user }} | grep -v "^[[:space:]]*$"
    register: cronentry
    ignore_errors: true

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ cronentry.stdout_lines }}"

  - cron:
      name: "test"
      job: "{{ item }}"
      state: present
      disabled: True
    with_items:
      - "{{ cronentry.stdout_lines }}"
```

This will do the job, but your mistake is that you gave all the cron jobs the name `test`, which will lead to overwrite all jobs with the same name.

```yaml
#Cron to auto restart app1
#Ansible: test
#* * * * * 0 2 * * * /web/apps/prod/apache/http-automation/bin/apachectl -k start


#Cron to auto restart app7

#Ansible: test
#* * * * * 0 2 * * * /web/apps/prod/apache/http-automation/bin/apachectl -k start


#Cron to restart Apache services on automation server

#Ansible: test
#* * * * * 0 2 * * * /web/apps/prod/apache/http-automation/bin/apachectl -k start
```

**################### Solution with unique cron jobs names ###################**

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    cron_user: root
  tasks:
  - name: Get enabled cron jobs
    shell: grep -v "^#" /var/spool/cron/crontabs/{{ cron_user }} | grep -v "^[[:space:]]*$"
    register: cronentry
    ignore_errors: true

  - name: get cron job name #Get the line before the line found in the previous task
    shell: fgrep -B1 "{{ item }}" /var/spool/cron/crontabs/{{ cron_user }}
    with_items: "{{ cronentry.stdout_lines }}"
    register: cronjob_name

  - cron:
      # Get the job name without '#Ansible: '
      name: "{{ item.stdout_lines[0] | regex_search('(?:#Ansible: )(.*)$', '\\1') | first }}"
      job: "{{ item.stdout_lines[1] }}"
      state: present
      disabled: True
    with_items:
      - "{{ cronjob_name.results }}"
```

Result:

```yaml
TASK [cron] *********************************
changed: [test-001] => (item={'changed': True, 'stdout': '#Ansible: execute playbook\n15 * * * * ansible-playbook  /web/playbooks/automation7/va_action.yml | tee -a /web/playbooks/automation7/cron.out', 'stderr': '', 'rc': 0, 'cmd': 'fgrep -B1 "15 * * * * ansible-playbook  /web/playbooks/automation7/va_action.yml | tee -a /web/playbooks/automation7/cron.out" /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root', 'start': '2022-08-30 15:03:07.266264', 'end': '2022-08-30 15:03:07.281987', 'delta': '0:00:00.015723', 'msg': '', 'invocation': {'module_args': {'_raw_params': 'fgrep -B1 "15 * * * * ansible-playbook  /web/playbooks/automation7/va_action.yml | tee -a /web/playbooks/automation7/cron.out" /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root', '_uses_shell': True, 'warn': False, 'stdin_add_newline': True, 'strip_empty_ends': True, 'argv': None, 'chdir': None, 'executable': None, 'creates': None, 'removes': None, 'stdin': None}}, 'stdout_lines': ['#Ansible: execute playbook', '15 * * * * ansible-playbook  /web/playbooks/automation7/va_action.yml | tee -a /web/playbooks/automation7/cron.out'], 'stderr_lines': [], 'failed': False, 'item': '15 * * * * ansible-playbook  /web/playbooks/automation7/va_action.yml | tee -a /web/playbooks/automation7/cron.out', 'ansible_loop_var': 'item'})

changed: [test-001] => (item={'changed': True, 'stdout': '#Ansible: start apache ctl\n0 2 * * * /web/apps/prod/apache/http-automation/bin/apachectl -k start', 'stderr': '', 'rc': 0, 'cmd': 'fgrep -B1 "0 2 * * * /web/apps/prod/apache/http-automation/bin/apachectl -k start" /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root', 'start': '2022-08-30 15:03:08.149322', 'end': '2022-08-30 15:03:08.165943', 'delta': '0:00:00.016621', 'msg': '', 'invocation': {'module_args': {'_raw_params': 'fgrep -B1 "0 2 * * * /web/apps/prod/apache/http-automation/bin/apachectl -k start" /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root', '_uses_shell': True, 'warn': False, 'stdin_add_newline': True, 'strip_empty_ends': True, 'argv': None, 'chdir': None, 'executable': None, 'creates': None, 'removes': None, 'stdin': None}}, 'stdout_lines': ['#Ansible: start apache ctl', '0 2 * * * /web/apps/prod/apache/http-automation/bin/apachectl -k start'], 'stderr_lines': [], 'failed': False, 'item': '0 2 * * * /web/apps/prod/apache/http-automation/bin/apachectl -k start', 'ansible_loop_var': 'item'})
```

Comment: What is the solution with names being unique and not the same?

Comment: @Ashar The answer is updated.

Comment: will enabling the cron have similar logic / approach? if you could add it to your answer

Comment: @Ashar It's possible, but that would be over-engineered. Search for specific words in commented lines, uncomment the line, remove the first four asterisks, get the name from the line above and enable the cron.